# Add new attribute to existing document

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, mongoengine

How do I add an attribute to all documents in collection using mongoengine?
I've tried several ways:

```
for d in MyDocuments.objects:
    d.attr = 'test'
    d.save()
```

This doesn't give any errors but it doesn't add new attribute to document.

I've also tried

```
MyDocuments.objects.all().update(set__attr='test')
```

This gives `InvalidQueryError: Cannot resolve field "attr"`

The same error happens when I try

```
for d in MyDocuments.objects:
    d.update(set__attr='test')
```

Specifically I'm trying to add `_cls` attribute because I enabled inheritance and I already have some objects in database that don't have that attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Finally this worked for me:

```
MyDocuments._get_collection().update_many({}, {'$set': {'_cls': 'MyDocuments.TTR'}})
```